# Python Fizzbuzz ignoring "and" but why?

Tags: python, fizzbuzz

I am literally two weeks into learning Python. I can get the infamous Fizzbuzz to print Fizz or buzz but it is ignoring my 'and' function and I am not understanding why? I could peek at completed solutions but I really dont want to do that and almost any research I do almost sneaks in the solution. I just want to understand what is wrong with that line. Instead of just grabbing completed code to turn in.

```
    for packers in range(1,101):
        if packers % 3 == 0:
            print("Fizz")
        elif packers % 5 == 0:
            print("buzz")
        elif packers % 3 == 0 and packers % 5 == 0:
            print("Fizzbuzz")
        else:
            print(packers)
```

Comment: You need to change the order of the tests. Anything that is both divisible by 3 and 5 will already be caught by the earlier test. For example 15 % 3 == 0. It never makes it to further tests.

Comment: One of the other cases matches first…

Comment: Ahhh, even when using those 'or', 'and' etc's the order of those matter? Ok I will do some rearranging of the code. I was thinking literally top-down based on the instructions. Tackling one line of the task first then moving to the next task etc.

Comment: The important thing isn't the `or` and `and`, it's the way that `if...elif` works.  The first matching block in the `if..elif..elif...else` chain is executed, all the rest are skipped.   Figuring out how to express the english-language instructions in the code correctly (which means changing the order in which you tell the computer to do things) is almost the entire point of the exercise.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that:

1. If the number is divisible by 3 or 5, either `packers%3` or `packers%5` evaluates to True before it even has the chance to look for the conditions below.
2. And when both of these 2 conditions don't pass (the number is not divisible by 3, and 5), there is not way that `packers%3` and `packers%5` will be 0.

You need to check if both are divisible first

```
  for packers in range(1,101):
        if packers % 3 == 0 and packers % 5 == 0:
            print("Fizz")
        elif packers % 5 == 0:
            print("buzz")
        elif packers % 3:
            print("Fizzbuzz")
        else:
            print(packers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should switch your second and third elif blocks.

Right now, you second elif block is kind of like a global set. It will print buzz for any number divisible by 5(Even if it is divisible by 5 and 3 both). And when this condition becomes false, the next condition can nevwr be true(since packers%5!=0, you just checked it).

Instead, first check if the number is divisible by both 3 and 5, if yes print fizzbuzz, if not continue to check if it is divisble by just 5